# Importing Git repo to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git

I have project in GIT that I can see on my local repo through command line interface. Now when I try to import GIT project I still see it on 'Select a wizard to use for importing projects' but when I check 'Import existing project' and click next to next window called 'Import Projects' the project goes missing.

I also tried importing project both by creating new project and coping source into it and also by importing existing project option but some how source does not import in all the attempts.

Comment: Since my project is a Maven projects hence I imported every thing as existing maven project and it seems to have worked but I have no clue why this happened. Basically I was trying to check all the option to import and this looks to have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if it has *'.project'* file. If no, you should create it somehow. For example, in gradle prjoject you can run *'gradle eclipse'* command, for maven project - something other. If it is just clean java project - create new Java project in Eclipse, create at least one class and save it. After that you may close eclipse, and copy all source files from project that you trying to import to folder, where created class is placed.

Comment: I used Maven project builder of eclipse to build the project and it seems to have worked. I am not user if thats the right way to do it. Also I am worried about building the project using Jenkins now. How should I test if jenkin is picking this repo for building this project ?

Comment: It is easy to config through Jenkins web-based UI, all you need GitLab plugin (and may be some other git-related plugins) installed
[GitLab plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitLab+Plugin)